# Z-coordinate has to be 1 or -1

Tags: navigation, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm starting to build a map using gmapping, but whenever I start slam_gmapping, the following warning is shown:

```
Laser has to be mounted planar! Z-coordinate has to be 1 or -1, but gave: 0.00000
```

This is one of the published transformations:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link2_broadcaster" args="0 0 0.1 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_link 100" />
```

When I change the X argument into 1 or -1 the warning is gone! I don't know why!.But I'm sure there is something wrong!! and  I need the X to be 0.

any idea?

UPDATE:

These are the frames in rviz:

[image: frames]

and I cannot change the values of the orientation in rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206791/z-coordinate-has-to-be-1-or--1/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error message is a bit confusing. It is just saying that the plane of the laser needs to be parallel to the ground plane. I would check the transform chain you are using (i.e., what is the orientation of base_link) and make sure it has z facing directly up or down. You can do this in rviz using the tf plugin.

if you're curious, the code producing the error message can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/gmapping/html/slam__gmapping_8cpp_source.html)

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-04-08**:
@Morgan Please see the update in the question

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-01-21**:
I have bumped into the same problem, have you fixed it, can you share how?